# What is meant by "treading water" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [an article](http://www.time-to-change.org.uk/blog/sometimes-think-im-not-depressed-just-lazy), I came across the following expression:

> I don’t have to pick up a textbook. I don’t have to talk to my friend. I don’t have to eat. When I wake it feels like I’ve been **treading water** for an eternity, I ache and my eyes are heavy.

[Wikipedia describes *treading water*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treading_water) as a method of swimming, but how is it being used or supposed to be understood in this writer's context? Is it common expression, or just used as a simile here?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tread+water

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tread+water), [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tread+water), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tread_water), [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-treading-water)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means that the person is not making any progress. They are exhausted and not feeling rested when they sleep. It's a metaphor for being drained and not progressing toward anything, in my opinion.

Either that, or they are so tired and sore upon waking that they feel they have been treading water all night instead of sleeping.

Comment: Why not make yourself sure before posting an answer? Please see also: my comment at OP.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a simile.  The writer feels thoroughly exhausted after having spent a lot of energy doing something. The person is just worn out by trying to keep his/her head afloat (figuratively speaking) with no real progress being made.

In short, the person is extremely tired.

Answer (score 0):

It normally means that the speaker or writer has put a lot of effort into something with little or no result. Its exact meaning in your example isn't entirely clear. Perhaps the wider context explains it.